# LUKS: encrypted device is much smaller than its host partition

Tags: linux, luks

To store personal data, I have encrypted a partition with LUKS but, according to the file manager, the resulting encrypted device is much smaller: **334 GB versus 385 GB**.  However, the Disk Utility in Debian says the encrypted device is 385 GB.  The file manager itself, before mounting the partition, says that it is 385 GB.

I have formatted the encrypted device with **ext4**.  In case I missed something, here is how I have created, formatted and mounted the device:

```
# cryptsetup --verify-passphrase --verbose luksFormat /dev/sdc3

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on /dev/sdc3 irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
Enter LUKS passphrase: 
Verify passphrase: 
Command successful.
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc3 data
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdc3: 
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/data
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
23470080 inodes, 93873669 blocks
4693683 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=0
2865 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968

Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

This filesystem will be automatically checked every 33 mounts or
180 days, whichever comes first.  Use tune2fs -c or -i to override.
```

Then the file manager allows me to mount the partition.  I have also tried to mount the partition manually:

```
# mount /dev/mapper/data /media/data
```

But the size difference is still there.  Closing and reopening the device does not help.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Software:

- Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 6
- File Manager: Nautilus 2.30.1
- Disk Utility 2.30.1

Comment: So, ext4 has reserved 5% for its own purposes.  Still there is a lot of space missing.  Maybe it is a bug in Gnome regarding byte conversions (sorry, but I can't find the article where I read this).

Answer (score 0):

Reason may be a few:

1. A calculation way - base of prefixes (1000 vs. 1024)

   334*1024*1024*1024/(1000*1000*1000) = 358.63

   You can check disk and partitions size by:

   `fdisk -l /dev/sdc`
2. Linux file systems reserving (by default) 5% (mkfs.ext4 -m PERCENT) free space accessed only by root (partition overflow protection)
3. File system structures have some size (e.g. superblocks, journals etc)